Best way to split jagged array on first element and fill with other elements
It's hard to describe this problem, but the code below should clarify.
Basically i start with an array where first element is another array of N size.
the rest of the array is a single element.   I want to split the first element a for every partion, fill with the remainder of the array:
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

data = [['100',    '200',      '300',   '400'],
        'val1',
        'val2',
        ]

ids = np.array_split(data[0], 2)
new_array = []
for id in ids:
        data[0] = id
        new_array.append(data[:])

new_array

So i end up with this:
[[['100', '200'], 'val1', 'val2'], 
 [['300', '400'], 'val1', 'val2']]

is this the best way of doing this that will also be fast for very large arrays?

this looks like a list(s).  Even the use of array_split makes a list.  Even if you make an object dtype array, the work is basically list like..  Even object dtype arrays are processed at list speeds.

This lacks sufficient context and is almost certainly an x/y problem. It's littered with the smell of incorrect but invisible decisions. Why use nested lists? Why use string representations of integers instead of integers? Why is any of this being done? The short answer to "is this the best way of doing this" is almost certainly no.

Even the input list being jagged is debatable. It just looks like two rectangular lists arbitrarily squashed together.

this is being done because i need to parallelize based on the first list in the array. each element in the resulting list are parameters to a query...the first being the ids (or the in clause), then the rest being single values for the remaining where clause...

i can basically then simply do tasks = {self.read_sql_async(sql, params=p) for p in params} where p is a single element of the resulting array i  have above.
this ofourse is not  a question about parallelization, but about whether i can optimize the splitting.  based on your answer u dont think so..that's ok

i dont get why so many want to solve a problem not asked.  the question is very specific, i have supplied code and an expected result along with a current impl that gets that result. if you havent any thing to contribute, fine...but its not feasible to post an entire program for 'context that is not really relevant. the question/problem is very specifiic..give the benefit of a doubt that its being asked for a reason.

Make a target object dtype array
res = np.empty(2,3, dtype=object)

fill from data[0]
res[:,0] = data[0].reshape(2,-1)

fill rest, with broadcasting
res[:,1:] = data[1:] # (2,)=>(1,2)=>(2,2)

I haven't tested this; just trying to picture the action in my head.  Exact shapes need to be generalized.
